We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later. Google Play Console
I am going through the verification of the Google Play Console developer account. Account verification is required for all existing Google Play developers, who created their Play Console Account before September 2023. In the contact information, I entered the phone number correctly, the country code is +7, but an error appears: We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later. Please help me solve this problem for the phone number with the country code +7, why is there such an error?
I entered the phone number correctly, the country code is +7, but an error appears: We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later.

If anyone finds a way, or a country that consistently works, please share it as a response here. The UI is absolutely inconsistent and it feels intentional that so many people from specific countries are not getting verified.

If you open the DevTools console in your browser, you may find an error related to this. I found a status 429. Like the error says, I'll probably have to try again later.

After several message between me and google support , they extended my deadline by two months and meanwhile there are looking for what it's the issue behind it , i will keep you updated

GET https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/verification:createChallenge 429 (Too Many Requests)

@Zee that's the error I have

@LuigiSiri You can't I had two cases with Google that lasted over a month, and they did NOTHING!.. Eventually, I decided to use a phone number from another country

@Zain, thanks! From which country was the phone that worked for you?

@LuigiSiri I got it from a friend of mine in Qatar

There is a google play support thread that so far leads to no where, but it seems like a general issue with many people from many different countries reporting the same thing.
It seems that some people have managed to make it work by using a phone number from another country, specifically a "developed country".
Just to make sure, here's Google support recommendations for this issue:

Enter your phone number in a valid international format:
Format: +(Country code)(Area code)(Phone number) Examples: +14155552671, +441234567890
Try both verification methods: text message or voice call.
Using a fixed-line phone if you’ve been using a mobile phone, or vice versa.
Ensure you can receive calls or texts from others.
Make sure your mobile phone has a strong signal.
Try verifying on another day or wait 24 - 72 hours between tries.
Try a different supported carrier.
Reset cache/cookies or Use an incognito window.

If nothing of the above works, I recommend to create a support ticket to get their attention.
UPDATE:
As @Abdelhakim's says, the issue we initially encounter is a temporary error (400 - "Precondition Check Failed" when viewed through the browser console). After multiple attempts, we start receiving the 429 - "Too Many Requests" error. At this point, the only option is to wait for the system to reset, as it will continue showing the same error no matter what phone number you use. For some users, this reset occurs after one day, while for others, it may take 10 days or even longer. It is advisable to be patient and avoid further attempts, as each attempt might reset the timer.
If you encounter the 400 error, stop immediately and consider the original advice to use a phone number from another country, particularly from a "developed country" to try again. It is also preferable to choose the call option over SMS.
If you have waited 10 to 15 days and continue to receive the 429 error, as the validation deadline (including extension) is approaching, you might consider, as a last resort, creating a new account and transferring your apps to it. Use the same strategy to validate the new account.

Did you to solve this problem? I can't do it

Nothing so far. But I do recommend that you create a support ticket here.

This is August, were you able to solve the issue? if so, kindly tell how. Thanks

@defemz, not exactly. But I added an update to this answer with what I have found.

@Luigi Siri, You mean google will grant extension if the initial two month deadline elapse? and do you think there is any negative implications(as per account status) if one use a foreign number?

@defemz, No, when the original deadline is approaching, an option should appear on the console home screen to request an extension. However, it needs to be requested before the original deadline elapses. In my case, I was granted an additional 22 days.
Regarding the phone number, I don't think it will be an issue, but we can change it back once Google resolves the problem.

Thanks. May I know, is your issue resolved? I came across many online rumor mentions that using phone number from developed countries might work. Not sure how true is that.

What is wrong with Google. Why are they treated like this with devs?

one more issue ticket in google support

I checked the list of 'Supported locations for developer and merchant registration': https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9306917?sjid=12450035320158006071-EU and developing countries are part.
I tried using Canadian/USA numbers for the verification - but none worked.
I've decided to create a ticket for Google here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/kyd?hl=en
I am keeping faith that they will respond to me within 2 business days as stated on the form ticket page.

Update August 9th 2024:
I today managed to verify our account after not trying it for about 3 days. I logged off my Google account, logged back in using incognito mode in Chrome. I verified my personal mobile number using SMS and verified our company number using voice call.
Original posting:
Same error here (for about 4 days now - trying to verify a +49 number from Germany). I found a special contact form to report issues during Google Play developer verification process
This form seems to be the best entry point to alert the Google team.

Did you use a German landline (Festnetz) or mobile phone number? We have issues with German landline number.

@guglhupf we used both. We verified the developer's mobile via SMS and company's landline via call. Make sure that you don't have an IVR or voice menu in front of your office number.

Hi @mwoop, I just wanted to confirm—were you able to resolve the issue after waiting for three days without submitting anything?

Yes, that's what I was writing above in my updated post.

I've been struggling with this problem recently, too. The error message I used to get was "We can't verify your phone number right now. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead", but there was no working option for phone call verification in my country.
I was frustrated much but then I got into this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/googleplayconsole/comments/1ewqhrb/comment/ljpk4gr. One member advised firstly to add the phone number as a recovery phone and as a 2 step verification phone number in google account and then only using this same number for verification during google console developer account creation process. And guess what - it helped! I added the phone to my account as 2fa and after a half day, about 12 hours later I tried to verify the number and it passed, google sent the verification code in sms.
I really hope this will help others, too.
By the way, if you have an android device such as a smartphone or a tablet - try using them during google developer account creation and phone verification processes instead of a browser on your laptop or desktop. I used a lenovo tablet.

Just for Googling a Google error, text is now "We can't verify your phone number at the moment. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead." Good to know they've changed the text of the message 3x at least without actually fixing their own issue :-/

I have reached Google Play Developer Console support and provided all of the required information for them to work with, but from my own observations it looks like ther SMS service has reached the quota in some regions so the service responds with 429 HTTP error.
I am issuing a problem with +380 country code but also have tried +48 country code to test with and it worked as expected so as a conclusion it's all about time for Google to recognize an issue and maybe pay some bills. It is not the local issue of specific Google Play Console Developer.
I'd recommend for all having that issue to contact Google Play Console support with "QUESTION MARK" located on top-right corner of Google Play Console home page. If you are not able to contact support with "EMAIL" just try to change "support" language to english. To send the request they will ask an information about specific app you have problem with - you can specify any, it does no matter for them. I'd also recommend to make a video of your screen where you trying to get a verification code just to speedup a proccess for a bit because that's the first thing they will ask you to provide

Have you fixed this problem? if so how?

@defemz I am still not able to get an SMS but for now I am able to get the code through the call which never actually happens, so the answer is NO, I still cannot proceed with +380 phone number

@silio Can you kindly update us do you have any progress so far? If yes, how? As, I am in the same situation right now.

@CheokYanCheng Support team just stuck at some point and did not solved the issue. One time I was able to schedule a call in Google Play Console but did not recevied any call on my phone after, so right before the deadline I decided to use my Polish phone number (+48) and it worked as expected, account verification passed successfully.
Google Play support has posted updates few time for me but all they were saying is "Please try again in 1 day and let us know if the issue is still persist"
Unfortunately the only solution here looks like to use the number from another country

The problem that many face is not the error of multiple requests 429; you will encounter error 429, but this error appears after exhausting the allowed number of attempts. The actual mistake is error 400, even if the phone number is correct. To confirm this error, stop trying to send the verification message for 10 days. Then, when you send the verification message, you will receive the same error message but with error 400. After repeating the attempts, error 429 will appear again.
I contacted Google about the issue and provided them with all the information related to the problem. They said that the team is working on a solution and that they are aware of the issue.

Yes i also got same feedback from them, I don't know if the account will be deleted when the deadline is up despite this challenge

did you get any feedback after that?

Hi, can you kindly update us do you have any progress so far? If yes, how? As, I am in the same situation right now.

My country code is +265(Malawi) It didn't work so I contacted someone from another country(south Africa) to use their  number it worked, You can edit the number later

I have the same error: We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later. I tried using other phone numbers, but it didn't help. Can you help please?

SAME ERROR. SAME BS. FOR +386

Use a number from a different country or network provider

same error "We can't verify your phone number right now. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead." for all Yemeni Phones Number start with +967

I once managed to order a confirmation call to +380, but there were problems with my bank (on my side)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I checked the requests when pressing the "Verify phone number" and it shows this error "We can't verify your phone number right now. If this error persists, try verifying by receiving a call instead."
The createChallenge POST request returns this response:
8. Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).
So i guess its a race between developers to send the validation code before the quote is exhausted.

Were you able to fix this, if so, how? Thanks

Just tested several times the next days. Its not related to the phone number at all its just the quota Google allocated for this. After the comment managed to verify the next day.

Thanks a lot. I will try mine again tomorrow.

May I know if you changed anything (email, phone number, website) between the first attempt and the successful one?

Nothing, just tried at different times and mostly when i remembered to test it.

Hi @mraiur,
Some users have mentioned that we should stop trying for a few days (some suggest 3 days, others 7 days) to prevent the system from blocking us further. May I ask, did you pause testing for a few days in between attempts?
Thanks!
